# Can't connect to network drive (attached to media player)

Tags: router, windows-10, network-shares

After a factory reset of my router, I can't connect anymore to the harddrives attached to my media player. Before this was no problem.

**What I do**

I try to connect to the drives by typing "\\192.168.1.70" in the Windows explorer bar or in the Run application.

**What I get**

In both cases it takes a lot of time for Windows to come up with this:

[image: Windows error message:"Windows cannot access \\192.168.1.70"]

**What I tried**

I can start this list with the things I already checked:

- Checked all wiring, rebooted every device
- Checked IP addresses

  - The Router is 192.168.1.1
  - The laptop is 192.168.1.12
  - The AC Ryan is 192.168.1.70 (static, setup in AC Ryan settings)
- Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 on both laptop and AC Ryan
- Default gateway is 192.168.1.1 on both laptop and AC Ryan
- I tried a more direct connection, cutting out the switch in between, making it laptop-router-AC Ryan.
- Tried with the laptop's firewall turned off, after which it worked, then I turned it on again to verify this as the cause, causing it to not work. But after that, turning off the firewall did not solve the problem anymore.
- I pinged the IP-address with router. It reports to have 5 packet transmitted and received with 0% packet loss and round trip time of 5 ms.
- I tried to reach the mediaplayer on another windows laptop (windows 8.1) --> Same issue
- I tried to reach the mediaplayer on a MacBook Air --> similar issue

**Setup**

Furthermore a list of equipment and network setup (please let me know if relevant details are missing):

- Media Player: AC Ryan Playon!HD mini 2
- Trying to connect from a HP laptop running Windows 10
- The laptop is connected to a Vigor 2130 router
- The AC Ryan is connected to a switch, which is connected to the same router.
- On the switch, there is also an Xbox One and a Philips Smart TV.
- All connections are wired.

**Can you help?**

Can someone provide a checklist of things to check to make it work?